# Opening a ear project in Net beans IDE 6.5

Tags: netbeans

Is it possible to open a .ear project in Net beans IDE 6.5

Thanks.

Comment: Plz, elaborate your question. It is very unclear.

Comment: Don't think so. It's an archive.

Comment: I have a EAR project that is developed using oracle JDeveloper 10.1. Now I want to open it using Net Beans 6.5 . I also have the .jws file for the project. So is there any way to import the EAR file or to open the .jws file using Net Beans? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

EAR file is Enterprise Archive. NETBeans IDE 6.5 cant open a ear file. You can use JDeveloper or Eclipse to open a .ear project.